# Is switching a KVM switch on 2 computers that are powered on problematic?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, osx-snow-leopard, kvm-switch, desktop-computer

If I have 2 computers that are running, and I constantly switch back and forth using a KVM switch to switch monitors (and mouse), is that a problem?

Can I blow a video card or short circuit anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that should not be a problem.  After all that is exactly the purpose of a KVM switch.

The KVM switch (that is operating properly) should properly load all PC connections so that nothing bad happens.

Note: I've used KVMs powered externally with a wall wart and powered from the connected PCs (the power from the keyboard and mouse ports).  The PC-powered KVM switches have one less cord, but the externally powered ones seem to operate more consistently. YMMV